# Scrapy Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType:

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I try to create my first spider **scraper** using scrapy
I use Dmoz as test, I get an error message:
TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType
But in the Debug I can see the right url

Code:

```
import scrapy
import urlparse


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=france&all=no&t=regional&cat=all"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.css('#site-list-content > div.site-item > div.title-and-desc')
        
        for site in sites:
            yield {
                'name': site.css('a > div.site-title::text').extract_first().strip(),
                'url': site.xpath('a/@href').extract_first().strip(),
                'description': site.css('div.site-descr::text').extract_first().strip(),
            }

        nxt = response.css('#subcategories-div > div.previous-next > div.next-page')
        next_page = nxt.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)          

        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Logs:

```
2016-10-18 11:17:03 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=france&start=20&type=next&all=no&t=regional&cat=all> (referer: http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=france&all=no&t=regional&cat=all)
2016-10-18 11:17:03 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=france&start=20&type=next&all=no&t=regional&cat=all> (referer: http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=france&all=no&t=regional&cat=all)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/ENV/bin/tutorial/dirbot/spiders/dmoz.py", line 25, in parse
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 51, in _set_url
    raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)
TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType:
2016-10-18 11:17:03 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-10-18 11:17:03 [scrapy] INFO: Stored json feed (20 items) in: test.json
2016-10-18 11:17:03 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Comment: `yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)` needs to be inside the if, you check  `if next_page is not None` but still make a Request regardless

Comment: Hi, I added it inside the if, I don't have the error but it is exporting only the first page and don't seems to execute the callback
`2016-10-18 11:45:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=france&start=20&type=next&all=no&t=regional&cat=all> (referer: http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=france&all=no&t=regional&cat=all)
2016-10-18 11:45:44 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)`

Comment: Then `next_page` is probably never finding anything, have you verified that it ever finds anything?

Comment: In the previous debug I post it's the right url, I assumed then that it found it (&start=20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your code here:

```
if next_page is not None:
    next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)          

yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

As Padraic Cunningham mentions in his commit: you `yield` the `Request` regardless of `next_page` is `None` or filled with an URL.

You can solve your problem by changing your code to this:

```
if next_page is not None:
    next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)          
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

where you put your `yield` inside your `if` block.

By the way you can change your `if` to the following:

```
if next_page:
```

because of Python's truth.

And because your spider stops working try to debug your application through **scrapy shell** where you can see if your CSS queries return values or not. You can also add an `else` to the previous `if` block which logs / prints a statement to the console that no `next_page` was found so you know that something is wrong with the site or your CSS queries.